# Multipling records base on difference of date between 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, range

Hi everyone i need help with a solution right here, the thing is that I need to get each id for each date within the creation date and the cancel date like the following images

[image: INPUT DATAFRAME]

[image: OUTPUT DATAFRAME]

I have the following code that "works" (but only with small datasets):

```
# `date_range` is slow so we only call it once
all_dates = pd.date_range(test['Date'].min(), test['Cancel_date'].max())

# For each day in the range, number them as 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
rank = all_dates.to_series().rank().astype(np.int64) - 1

# Change from `2020-01-01` to "day 500 in the all_dates array", for example
start = test['Date'].map(rank).values
end = test['Cancel_date'].map(rank).values

start = start.astype(int)
end = end.astype(int)

# This is where the magic happens. For each row, instead of saying
# `start_date = Jan 1, 2020` and `end_date = Jan 10, 2020`, we are
# creating a range of days: [500, 501, ... 509]
indices = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(s,e+1) for s,e in zip(start, end)]))

# Now map day 500 back to Jan 1, 2020, day 501 back to Jan 2, 2020, and so on
dates = np.take(all_dates, indices)

# Align the rest of the columns to the expanded dates
duration = (end - start + 1).astype(np.int64)
ids = np.repeat(test['internal_id'], duration)
start_date = np.repeat(test['Date'], duration)
end_date = np.repeat(test['Cancel_date'], duration)

# Assemble the result
result = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': start_date,
    'end_date': end_date,
    'internal_id': ids,
    'Date': dates
})
```

The problem is that when I have a 16k records dataframe the indices becomes too big getting a memory error

```
# This is where the magic happens. For each row, instead of saying
# `start_date = Jan 1, 2020` and `end_date = Jan 10, 2020`, we are
# creating a range of days: [500, 501, ... 509]
indices = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([range(s,e+1) for s,e in zip(start, end)]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `datetime` using the specific format of the column (`%d-%b`) plus the year the data is related to it (`"%d-%b-%Y"`).
Use `apply` with `axis=1` to iterate over each row with the function `data_range`. Use `close="left"` with `data_range` to indicate that you only want the closed interval on the left side date of the interval. This will avoid the creation of an extra pair of dates with equal values. Use `explode` to transform each `data_range` element into a row.

As a consequence of the half-closed interval we now use `fillna` where there is an empty range (rows with the same creation and cancel dates). After that, convert the dates back to the desired date format with `dt.strftime`.

File *sample.csv* used as input

```
id  Date    CancelDate daysDiff
aaaaa   01-mar  01-mar  0
bbbb    01-mar  05-mar  4
cccc    03-mar  06-mar  3
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", sep='\s+')

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + "-2020", format="%d-%b-%Y")
df["CancelDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df.CancelDate + "-2020", format="%d-%b-%Y")
df = df.drop(columns=["daysDiff"])

df["Date"]= df.apply(lambda x:
    pd.date_range(start=x.Date, end=x.CancelDate, closed="left")
, axis=1)

dout = df.explode("Date").reset_index(drop=True)
dout["Date"] = dout.Date.fillna(dout.CancelDate)

dout["CancelDate"] = dout.CancelDate.dt.strftime("%d-%b")
dout["Date"] = dout.Date.dt.strftime("%d-%b")

print(dout)
```

Output from *dout*

```
      id    Date CancelDate
0  aaaaa  01-Mar     01-Mar
1   bbbb  01-Mar     05-Mar
2   bbbb  02-Mar     05-Mar
3   bbbb  03-Mar     05-Mar
4   bbbb  04-Mar     05-Mar
5   cccc  03-Mar     06-Mar
6   cccc  04-Mar     06-Mar
7   cccc  05-Mar     06-Mar
```